# Checking if a system of linear equations admits a positive solution

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I use Mathematica to check if a system of the form $A x > 0$ admits a solution $x\geq 0$ where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. All inequalities are to be understood componentwise. Thanks a lot!

An example of such a matrix $A$ would be $$A = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The goal is to have a function that takes an arbitrary matrix a as an input and returns True or False depending on whether or not such a solution exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also look at it in general:

```
mat = Array[a, {3, 2}];
vec = Array[x, 2];
Reduce[mat.vec > 0 && vec >= 0]
```

This gives a fairly verbose description of the relationships between the a[i,j] that must hold in order the the inequality to be fulfilled.

For your specific example

```
a = {{-1, -1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, -1}};
vec = Array[x, 4];
Reduce[a.vec > 0 && vec >= 0]

x[4] >= 0 && x[1] > x[4] && x[3] > x[1] - x[4] && 0 <= x[2] < -x[1] + x[3] + x[4]
```

You get a nice concise answer. And if there is no answer, it simply returns False:

```
a = {{-1, -1, -1, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
vec = Array[x, 4];
Reduce[a.vec > 0 && vec >= 0]  

False.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a possibility of doing this when the dimensions of a are not known a priori?

Comment: If you can't specify the matrix, it's hard to see what kind of answer you might expect to see.

Comment: I am looking for a function which just returns true false depending on whether or not a solution exists. Thanks again your answer is super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance). I use Mathematica 12, in order to use both [`VectorGreater`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorGreater) and [`PositiveReals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositiveReals):

```
FindInstance[
    VectorGreater[{A.x, 0}] && x ∈ Vectors[4, PositiveReals],
    x
]
```

> {{x -> {5/4, 1/4, 1, 1}}}

When typeset in Mathematica, the above looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is a great solution.